# Can't get everything in the JSON from Enjin

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get everything but some of the string in the JSON doesn't show up in my script. Could someone find the mistake in my code?

```
$url = "http://natomilcorp.com/api/get-users";
$jsonString = file_get_contents($url);

$obj = json_decode($jsonString, true);

$sptr = 0;
$x = 0;
$itemID = 1;

while (is_numeric($itemID)) {
    if ($x == 1) {
        $findUserID = 0;
        $findUserIDEnd = '":';
        $sptr = strpos($jsonString, $findUserID, $sptr + 1) + 2;
        $eptr = strpos($jsonString, $findUserIDEnd, $sptr + 1);
        $length = $eptr - $sptr;
        $itemID = substr($jsonString, $sptr, $length);

    } else {
        $findUserID = 'datejoined":"';
        $findUserIDEnd = '"';
        $sptr = strpos($jsonString, $findUserID, $sptr + 1) + 27;
        $eptr = strpos($jsonString, $findUserIDEnd, $sptr + 1);
        $length = $eptr - $sptr;
        $itemID = substr($jsonString, $sptr, $length);

    }

$findUserName = '"username":"';
$findLastSeen = '"lastseen":"';
$findDateJoined = '"datejoined":"';

$findEnd = '"';


$sptr = strpos($jsonString, $findUserName, $sptr + 1) + 12;
$eptr = strpos($jsonString, $findEnd, $sptr + 1);
$length = $eptr - $sptr;
$itemName = substr($jsonString, $sptr, $length); // Name

$sptr = strpos($jsonString, $findLastSeen, $sptr + 1) + 12;
$eptr = strpos($jsonString, $findEnd, $sptr + 1);
$length = $eptr - $sptr;
$itemLastSeen = substr($jsonString, $sptr, $length); // Name

$sptr = strpos($jsonString, $findDateJoined, $sptr + 1) + 14;
$eptr = strpos($jsonString, $findEnd, $sptr + 1);
$length = $eptr - $sptr;
$itemDateJoined = substr($jsonString, $sptr, $length); // Name


$LastSeen = date("F j, Y, g:i a", $itemLastSeen);
$DateJoined = date("F j, Y, g:i a", $itemDateJoined);


if (is_numeric($itemID)) {
    $x +=1;
    echo $x . ". INSERT INTO `player`(`id`,`name`,`enjinId`) VALUE (" ."'$itemID','$itemName', '$itemID'" . ")<br>";
}

}
```

There should be atleast 80 members but I only see 46

Thanks for helping me! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have more than one mistake, I dont know what your purpose 
answer on the following questions and help me to help you :)

1. Why you dont use the $obj ?

   ```
   $content = file_get_contents('http://natomilcorp.com/api/get-users');
   $array = json_decode($content,TRUE);
   var_dump($array);
   echo count($array);

       9430088 => 
       array (size=7)
        'username' => string '[PVT.]Flynn, C.' (length=15)
        'forum_post_count' => string '1' (length=1)
        'forum_votes' => string '0' (length=1)
        'forum_up_votes' => string '0' (length=1)
        'forum_down_votes' => string '0' (length=1)
        'lastseen' => string '1394941661' (length=10)
        'datejoined' => string '1394839236' (length=10)
      9442152 => 
        array (size=7)
         'username' => string 'Rct. Evanicki, K.' (length=17)
         'forum_post_count' => string '0' (length=1)
         'forum_votes' => string '0' (length=1)
         'forum_up_votes' => string '0' (length=1)
         'forum_down_votes' => string '0' (length=1)
         'lastseen' => string '1394926383' (length=10)
         'datejoined' => string '1394910499' (length=10)
   ```

   Number Of Items: 90
2. Why do you increment the id ? if the id define PK (Primary Key) and AI (Auto Increment)
   you don't need to increment manually

   $queries .="INSERT INTO `player`(`name`,`enjinId`) VALUE ('".$itemName."', '".$itemID."')";
3. Why you print the insert and not insert them with PHP code ?
4. Why Id and itemID Inserted with the same value ?

Comment: It was just a example. I wanted to get data from each user id and after using it with my website and Enjin API to get other data.

Or maybe could you tell me how to get id for all the JSON. That's what I'm having problem with.

Comment: $all_ids = array_keys(json_decode(file_get_contents($url),TRUE));